# Azure Data factory Transformation Pipeline- Screen resolution issue

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am facing Azure Data factory screen resolution issue. my screen resolution is 50% still I am not able to see the expression I am trying to build.
if anyone from the team has faced this issue before, please help us resolve[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwVCe.jpg) this issue.

Comment: Did you tried using other browser, such us Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try Edge browser!

It works.

Answer (score 0):

This is Daniel from the product group. Sorry you are facing this issue! To help us diagnose the this, can you answer the following questions:

1. What browser are you using?
2. When did you start experiencing this?

While this is probably not helpful, please refresh the page and see if this issue still occurs.

Any additional information provided will be of great assistance!

Comment: I am using Google chrome. I experienced this from Friday. tried refreshing clear history as well.